# Socket.io loaded with require.js is not available globally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, requirejs

Why socket.io (1.0.x) loaded with require.js is not available globally? With version 0.9.x everything is working fine...

After successfull loading(with Require.js) from //cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.4.js when i try connect on my node.js server i have following error:

```
  var socket = io('http://nodeapp.herokuapp.com');
        console.log(socket);
  ReferenceError: io is not defined
```

Comment: One of the primary reasons to use AMD is to prevent leaking globals. If you want it to be global, just do `require(['socketio'], function(io){ window.io = io })`.

Comment: There appears to be a conflict between require.js and socket.io 1.0.x, and it seems to happen if socket.io is loaded any time after require.js is loaded. It doesn't matter if you load the socket.io using the require([]) function or not.